# Create ggplot2 grid with pairs of levels in a factor as variables to "compare"

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let's see if I manage to explain properly my goal...

I have a huge amount of data points belonging to various categories controlled by a factor variable. As by plotting all of them together it's impossible to observe if they have any specific structure (for instance, regions with a higher density of a specific class), not even when using a low `alpha`, I am trying to show in a grid only two of such categories at a time (plus single categories in the diagonal).

With the extremely hacky code of the example below I have managed to achieve my goal:

```
fact <- factor(c('a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'c'))

x <- c(1, 2, -1, 3, -4, 0.5)
y <- c(3, 1, 0.5, 6, 1, 2)

df <- data.frame(class = fact, fact = fact, x = x, y = y)

fact2 <- unique(df$fact)[
  as.numeric(unique(df$fact)) %x% rep(1, nrow(df))]

df <- do.call("rbind", replicate(length(unique(df$fact)),
                       df, simplify = F))
df$fact2 <- fact2

df2 <- df
df2$fact <- df$fact2
df2$fact2 <- df$fact

df3 <- unique(rbind(df, df2))

ggplot(subset(df3, as.numeric(fact) >= as.numeric(fact2)),
   aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = class), size = 4) +
  facet_grid(fact ~ fact2)
```

[image]

but it requires to inflate the data frame by replicating explicitly a data point to appear in all possible combinations of factors. More precisely, the number of rows is increased in a quadratic order. Obviously, this is not a problem with a dataset like the one in the example, but I have the feeling that it will become extremely inefficient as soon as I use my real data. Apart from being a terribly ugly code.

Can you help me find a more elegant/efficient way to address this problem?

(If you need further clarification about what this hacky code is doing or why I am doing it in a specific way don't hesitate to ask)

In addition to that, as you can see, I am using `subset` in order to avoid repeated information to appear in the grid, but it would be nicer if there was a way to even skip showing the empty canvas. In other words, do you know if the previous plot can be converted to a "staircase" shape in some way?

Cheers,

Fran

Comment: A few things. 1) you didn't really clearly express your goal, although I think it is to find structure in your data, by looking at the coordinates pairwise (maybe `ggpairs` would be worth looking into?). 2) you didn't really express what your data looks like. How many factors do you actually  have (a,b,c,....), and how many dimensions (x,y,...), and what values do those dimensions range over (here half integers from -4 to 6). 3) You are worried about inefficiency as the data gets big, but you didn't tell us how big the data really is. 4) You say "hacky", but the code is not really big or messy

Comment: HI! And thanks for the reply. I don't know if it really matters what my specific data looks like because I would like to have a general function that could be re-used when necessary, but I will try to clarify it a little further:
  1. My main goal is to identify if there are "boundaries" between data points belonging to one category or the other. In other words, trying to observe if the two specified categories (namely `x` and `y`) are able to separate classes.

Comment: (2) I always have 10 different levels/categories in the factor, several variable sizes (84, 85, 252, 797, ...) but I only want to visualize the two "top ones" each time, and their values are double values usually between [-8, 2]
(3) The current data sets contain 10.000 observations each but could be bigger or smaller at will as we generate them by simulation.
(4) The code IS extremely hacky even if it's not very big, as I achieve my goal by inflating the dataset just because I don't find any other way of doing it, but I'm pretty sure that a single factor column should be enough to control it

Comment: By the way, thank you very much for pointing me to `ggpairs`. It might be useful for the "staircase" shape. I'll check

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach using the `cowplot` package and making separate plots.

```
pl <- apply(expand.grid(levels(df$class), levels(df$class)), 1,
  function (cl) {
    ggplot(subset(df, class %in% cl), aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
      geom_point(aes(colour = class), size = 4) +
      xlim(range(df$x)) + ylim(range(df$y)) +
      scale_color_discrete(limits = levels(df$class), guide = FALSE)
  } )

cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = pl)
```

[image]

You lose the legend, but `cowplot` has nice functions to add some labels yourself.

Regardless, when it comes to performance, this approach will also make copies of your data, as `ggplot2` stores that data in it's object (in this case the subsets). I don't expect it will do much better in that respect than your own solution.